# How to remove one set from another?

Tags: python, set

```
set1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
set2 = [3, 5]

...
result = [1, 7]
```

I was trying something like

```
set1.remove(set2)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Those are not sets but lists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so how do you denote `set([1,3,5,7])`?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's more simple than that

```
set1 = set([1, 3, 5, 7])
set2 = set([3, 5])

result = set1 - set2
```

Answer (score 5):

Use actual sets first:

```
set1 = set([1, 3, 5, 7])
set2 = set([3, 5])
```

or, in python 2.7 or 3:

```
set1 = {1, 3, 5, 7}
set2 = {3, 5}
```

then use the [`.difference_update` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference_update):

```
set1.difference_update(set2)
```

or do an in-place subtraction:

```
set1 -= set2
```

This mutates `set1` in place. If you only need to see the differences, just use subtraction:

```
result = set1 - set2
```